# Count no. of sub-matrices with given constraints from a matrix?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

This is a question asked in one job interview. I would like to know the best optimal algorithm for getting desired results. 
The question is : Given you have a (n x m) matrix with some numbers in it.
Now you have to count the no of matrices of size >= (2 x 2) which will have following two conditions :

- It should have at-least two 1's ;
- Two of the corner elements of matrix are equal.

I know the brute force algorithm of taking all elements of matrix 2 x 2 and greater; then counting the no. of 1's and checking 6 possible conditions of corner elements any two of them being equal.
I want to know the way of dealing with these problems or any source as I could not found anything on *"GeeksForGeeks"*  or *StackOverFlow* itself , in most optimized way.

Comment: Well I am asking for just an approach to solve the problem in few lines , that one would take. Any data structure would be required or something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hint to an optimized way.

First build a (n,m) matrix that counts the number of `1` in the (1-i, 1-j) submatrix: n*m operations, n*m memory

Now for each element of the matrix, search for all elements after of below that are equal

- if on the same row you can use any row below to have a matrix with 2 corners equal
- if on the same column, you can use any column after to have a matrix with 2 corners equal
- if neither on the same row nor same column you have exactly one matrix with 2 corners equal
- the difference of elements of the extreme corners of the equivalent matrix of the pre-calculated one is the number of ones in the submatrix
- as soon as one submatrix has more than 2 ones in it all submatrix including it will also have: you can use it to short-circuit full analysis

The above is only the rough edges and there is still some work to design an algorythm, but it should be a little better than brute force for big enough matrices...